# Setting up Unity using ovr 1.0.3 for Gear VR

Tags: android, oculus, gear-vr

So i'm following this tutorial to learn mobile VR development :
http://www.samsung.com/us/samsungdeveloperconnection/developer-resources/gear-vr/apps-and-games/exercise-1-creating-a-unity-project.html

Unfortunately, the tutorial is outdated, and requires me to import package /VrSamples/Unity/UnityIntegration/UnityIntegration.unitypackage
which is present in the oculus mobile sdk v0.6.0.1. However, i'm using the latest v1.0.3 and under /VRSamples theres only one folder - Native and i cannot find the UnityIntegration.unitypackage package to import anywhere within the sdk folder. Any help towards solving this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, but reading a little bit more I found that the UnityIntegraion.unitypackage was on the engine integration section, in my case Oculus Utilities for Unity 5 V1.8.0